Regular expression for Python to detect a string and find code block corresponding to the string
I have below text
text = '''
here are some examples
@with some text
@then some more text
@ some more@text @moretext probedetail
how are you
something is going on
}
how has it been
weather is good
'''

I want to do the following -

Find a string 'probedetail'.
Find @ closest to 'probedetail'. It has to be before probe detail, but not in the same line. So we need to search in above lines.
After finding closest @ in above line.
Start from that @ and go below till first } is found.
Extract the text.

So in above example I am expecting the below as answer-
@then some more text \n
@ some more@text @moretext probedetail

Can you clarify what the rules are? Is it "find probedetail, move one line up, find @ and capture until }" or something else?

If my first interpretation is correct (which I doubt), it'd be \n(@(.*)\n(.*)probedetail([^}]+)})

you are right, but I want a more general soultion than moving a line up I want to find the  closest @ above the line where we find 'probedetail' right now I have hard coded the patter for 3 @ pattern I am using now is r'(@[^@]?@[^@]?@[^@]?probedetail.?})'. I am looking for more general thing so that I do not have to hard code for 3 @. I am trying to extract JAVA code block

@ can be one line above or more from the line where I find 'probedetail'

this pattern r'(@[^@]?@[^@]?@[^@]?probedetail.?})' will not match to above data it is from my work. Where there are 2 @ in the same of probedetail and 1 @ above. I want a general solution other than going 1 line above

OK, this is how I understand the requirements now: 1. find probedetail, 2. go one line up, 3. keep searching backwards until the first @ and 4. capture from there until }.  This is what I got (note, no hard-coded number of @): r"\n(@([^@]*)\n(.*)probedetail([^}]+)})"

If the @ above probedetail doesn't need to start at the beginning of a line, it could be this: r"\n[^@]*(@([^@]*)\n(.*)probedetail([^}]+)})"

^.*$\n.*?probedetail$[\s\S]*?} DEMO

Is it guaranteed that the string 'probedetail' will be present?  If so, must it be after '@' beginning a previous line and before ';'? Note that you should answer comments that seek clarification by editing your question rather than replying in comments. Questions need to be self-contained; it should not be necessary for readers to read all the comments in order to understand the question.

The syntax of Java annotations makes a general solution much harder than the given example implies. Annotations can take parameters within parentheses which can be broken over several lines, and the parameters can be lists, or arbitrary strings - e.g. @Foo({Enum.X, Enum.Y}) @Bar(z="{@}"). Also, unlike Python decorators, annotations aren't restricted to being anchored to the beginning of the preceding line: they can appear anywhere within the code. So when the OP says they want a "more general solution" to "extract JAVA code block", that is going to require very precise qualification.

Thank you. I have tried to change my question to be more clear. I am not looking to go till one line above only, I am looking for more general solution.

@Harneet.Lamba What's wrong with the solutions you've already been given?

My solution is
(@[^@]*?)(\n.*?probedetail[^}]*})

Obviously the (\n.*?probedetail[^}]*}) portion is the anchor about which the first portion must fit. The (@[^@]*?) finds the last @ before the line with probedetail as everything in between cannot contain another @. I tested this in Notepad++ but converted my \R to the \n that seems correct for Python, my mistake if I'm wrong.

There's no need for non-greedy quantifiers, and no need for capture groups.

I wasn't necessarily providing a python regex as I'm not fluent in that. However using regex101.com and removing the non-greedy quantifier showed it saved about 40% of the steps. So yes it could be beneficial to be greedy in this instance.
